# Program outputting wrong sum

Tags: c, sum

`team1sum` / `team2sum` is supposed to get the sum of each `playerWeight1` / `playerWeight2` and print it out.

My `team1sum` and `team2sum` are printing out wrong numbers.

The right output can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qjzF.png).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i, howManyPlayers, playerWeight1, playerWeight2, 
        team1sum = 0, team2sum = 0;

    scanf("%d", &howManyPlayers);

    for (i = 0; i < howManyPlayers; i++){
        scanf("%d", &playerWeight1);
        scanf("%d", &playerWeight2);
        team1sum = team1sum + playerWeight1;
        team2sum = team2sum + playerWeight2;
    }

    if (team1sum > team2sum){
        printf("Team 1 has an advantage\n");
        printf("Total weight for team 1: %d\n", &team1sum);
        printf("Total weight for team 2: %d", &team2sum);
    }

    else {
        printf("Team 2 has an advantage\n");
        printf("Total weight for team 2: %d\n", &team2sum);
        printf("Total weight for team 1: ", &team1sum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove `&` from printf statements.

Comment: What is your input? What is the output you expect from that input? What is the output you are getting? Edit your question to include all of that information as text, not images.

Comment: "`printf("Total weight for team 1: " /*...*/`" is missing a `%d`.

Comment: Why is your right output a PNG image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your printf needs the int, not the address of the int, so remove the & operator.

```
printf("Total weight for team 2: %d\n", team2sum);
printf("Total weight for team 1: %d", team1sum);
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it seems that the actual sum is being calculated correctly.

By removing the `&` from the print statements, you should obtain the expected output.

Remember that when you print using `printf`, the format does matter, and printing a `&` to an `int` is not the same thing as printing an `int`.